# How to switch from separate arrays per type to a single array with all values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to switch the format of some of my data because I am trying to switch to a different API for a project I'm working on, and I'm honestly stumped.

We previously had data in this kind of format (simplified):

```
[
    [ // data belonging to 1/1/20 dataset
       {x: "6:00 AM", y: 1000, sourceData: "1/1/20"}, 
       {x: "6:30 AM", y: 1200, sourceData: "1/1/20"}...
    ],
    [ // data belonging to 1/2/20 dataset
        {x: "6:00 AM", y: 2000, sourceData: "1/2/20"}, 
        {x: "6:30 AM", y: 2400, sourceData: "1/2/20"}...
    ], 
    ... ... (other potential sets of data)
]
```

However, now we have to try and change the data to this kind of format:

```
[ 
    {x: "6:00 AM", 1/1/20: 1000, 1/2/20: 2000, blah: "Other data"},
    {x: "6:30 AM", 1/1/20: 1200, 1/2/20: 2400, blah: "Other data2"} ...
    ... // other x values
]
```

I'm stuck on how to optimally go through all the arrays in the first array and convert it into just one array. Is there a simple way to do this or will it just involve having to loop through every array and sub array for all values with the same X? I am pretty new to Javascript so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! 
(I gave it a shot but it turned into a bit of a mess.)

Comment: your expected data format is wrong, why are you expecting duplicate keys?

Comment: @SunilLama Hi, I'm not sure what you're referring to as incorrect - the only thing that needs to be unique in the new format is the value of X. Could you clarify?

Comment: What API are you switching to? Is this the expected input that they describe in their documentation?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier It's for recharts - from what I see, there's an object for each X value and the Y values corresponding to separate lines are actually just different properties on the same object. (And lines are based on a defined property - in the case I'm working on, it would be the dataset "1/1/20", "1/2/20", etc.). https://jsfiddle.net/9s8ngv5e/

Previously, we had different arrays for each "line" data but restrap expects a single array with different properties used to define a "line"'s data.

Comment: @CustardBun, is the answer good enough for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest first grouping the data by your time, then remove the keys to get the expected output. I believe that the mapping is done using the sourceData value, so for each timeline it will just keep on adding the blah key that you are expecting.

```js
var arr = [
  [ // data belonging to 1/1/20 dataset
    {
      x: "6:00 AM",
      y: 1000,
      sourceData: "1/1/20"
    },
    {
      x: "6:30 AM",
      y: 1200,
      sourceData: "1/1/20"
    }
  ],
  [ // data belonging to 1/2/20 dataset
    {
      x: "6:00 AM",
      y: 2000,
      sourceData: "1/2/20"
    },
    {
      x: "6:30 AM",
      y: 2400,
      sourceData: "1/2/20"
    }
  ],
];

var res = arr.reduce((ini, curr, idx) => {
  curr.forEach(data => {
    if (ini[data.x]) {
      ini[data.x][data.sourceData] = data.y;
    } else {
      ini[data.x] = {
        x: data.x
      };
      ini[data.x][data.sourceData] = data.y;
    }
  });
  return ini;
}, []);
var expected = Object.values(res);
console.log(expected);
```